# PHP - Illegal string offset & Undefined index errors

Tags: php, arrays

The following code works fine on PHP5.6, but is failing on PHP7 and I can't see why.

```
$test = array();
                        
foreach ( $rows as $key => $row ) {
    
    if ( $key == 0 ) {
        $headers = array();
        foreach ( $row as $column => $header ) {
            $headers[] = $header;
        }
        continue;
    }
    
    if ( strlen( $row[ 1 ] ) > 0 ) {
        for ( $c = 1; $c < count( $row ); $c++ ) {
            $test[ $key ][ $headers[$c] ] = ( isset( $row[ $c ] ) ) ?  $row[ $c ] : NULL; <-- This is line 42
        }   
    }
    
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r ( $test );
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

I get errors:

PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'Site' in test.php on line 42

PHP Notice:  Undefined index: site_ns-4esw in /test.php on line 42

This should produce an array that looks like this.

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [Site] => site_ns-4esw
            [Venue Location] => NAW-1657-Clo
            [Members] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Site] => site_na-67spr
            [Venue Location] => NWS-4735-Pol
            [Members] => 10
        )

)
```

Can any one point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: Which is line 42?

Comment: I've updated the post to show line 42, but it's  `$test[ $key ][ $headers[$c] ] = ( isset( $row[ $c ] ) ) ?  $row[ $c ] : NULL;` and the error seems to be `$headers[$c]`  thanks

Comment: The *warning* indicates an undefined index that you're trying to use, but without including the original array you're operating on, I'm not sure what we can do to help. Once you paste in the original array, hopefully it will be clear what is incorrect

Comment: Since you have a lot going on just on that one line, you're going to have to do some debugging. Add some var_dumps for each of your variables and keys. `Illegal string offset` means that you're trying to get an array key on a string.